# String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 60
String or binary data would be truncated.

I am trying to insert into a temp table. This proc has been working through testing fine until yesterday. I got the truncate error, fixed a field and it began working. Today I ran it and I get the truncate error again. I tried setting all the fields in the insert equal to max and 8000 but to no avail. Is there some sort of data limit restriction to temp tables. I ran evaluations of all the max lengths of the input and all of them are within limit of the table construction.

The Temp Table is pretty large but is in my opinion necessary.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you tell us which database you're using, give us the layout of the temp table, and give us the insert command.

Comment: Without seeing the code we can only randomly guess.

Answer (score 13):

gbn is undoubtedly correct. You're evaluation of the lengths is off.

However if you want to just let the truncate happen and ignore it you can just [SET ANSI_WARNINGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx) off

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I didn't know SET ANSI WARNING did this! (I've used it for aggregates etc occasionally)

Answer (score 4):

1. Check for trailing spaces: by default, [SET ANSI_PADDING is ON.](http://SET%20ANSI_PADDIN)
2. Check the data length using [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx): [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) this trims trailing spaces