# Auto truncate fields with ODBCDataAdapter on INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: c#, odbc

I am updating a database using `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter`. I also don't know what table or fields I'm updating until runtime. The code I have works and is roughly equivalent to the following:

```
{
    mConn = new OdbcConnection(connectionStr);
    mConn.Open();

    mDataSet = new DataSet();
    mDataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(selectStatement, mConn);
    mCmdBldr = new OdbcCommandBuilder(mDataAdapter);

    var trans = mConn.BeginTransaction();
    mDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = trans;

    mDataAdapter.Fill(mDataSet, tableName);

    mDataTable = mDataSet.Tables[tableName];
    mDataTable.Rows.Add(mNewDataTableRow);
    mDataAdapter.Update(mDataSet, tableName);

    trans.Commit();
}
```

The above is stripped down from my actual code, but hopefully gives an idea of how I'm using the DataAdapter. As I say, it works, for the most part...

It does of course fail if I try to insert to many characters into a SQL Server VARCHAR column, in which case I get the following error (in this case, I'm writing to SQL Server, but the database could be something else):

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException occurred   HResult=0x80131937
>   Message=ERROR [22001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]String or binary data would be truncated.

My **question** is this:

**Is there any way in which I can get the `OdbcDataAdapter` to *automatically* truncate text fields?**

I understand I can turn off ANSI_WARNINGS in the database if I'm using SQL Server, but I might not be, and I don't want to do that anyway because in most cases I would *want* the above exception to be thrown. I also understand that I can inspect the constraints on the fields myself and truncate the data before I insert it, but I'm looking for something less manual. I'll write that code if I have to, but I'd rather not have to.

I've looked at setting the `OdbcParameter.Size` property, but this simply throws an exception in a different place. Similarly with `DataColumn.MaxLength`.

I've also looked at setting `DataSet.EnforceConstraints`, but that doesn't prevent the above error when actually updating.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just truncate the string yourself before trying to save it to the database?

Comment: Well, In order to do so, I would need to determine, at runtime, which columns are varchar, and find out what length they are. I would then need to check every set on those columns, and truncate if necessary, which is extra code that will be unnecessary most of the time. Not particularly difficult - the only _reason_ I wouldn't do that is if there is a simpler way. If there isn't then I guess that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server you really should know those sizes anyway, since otherwise you will get plan cache pollution. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ivandonev/plan-cache-pollution-or-how-important-it-is-to-properly-define-parameters-in-code/

Comment: Hmm, interesting, although there's no guarantee that the user of the application _will_ be using SQL Server. I'm looking for an ODBC solution to truncating the fields.

Comment: Sure, but for those using SQL Server **right now** they are getting cache pollution. For the benefit of those users your code needs to know column size. In which case your code has the info it needs to do the truncation itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5504628/34092 may be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks, but that refers to setting ANSI_WARNINGS off, which I don't want to do, and in any case, that would only work for SQL Server. Likewise, the cache pollution is interesting, but potentially only relevant for SQL Server, and the example in the link you post does not use ODBC. These are all worth noting, but my question is still - Is there an automatic way to truncate text fields with ODBC? One that is DBMS agnostic.

Comment: No there is not.